# conectar base de datos mysql con django

Tags: mysql, django

Hola tengo mi proyecto hecho en django pero lo hice guiandome de un tuto que usaba sqlite3 pero yo ya tengo mi base de datos creada ya mysql y quiero conectar, se que modifico el settings.py pero no se que mas modificarle :/ solo tengo una sola tabla llamada marks con los campos id, nombre, address, lat, lng, y tipo los mismo que uso y muestro en mi aplicacion alguien me podria guiar? no encuentro mucha informacion al respecto ya que todos o hacen la base de datos de 0 o usan sqlite3 que no entiendo ucho dejo mi codigo por si quieren echarle una mirada [AQUI](https://www.dropbox.com/s/01rh89cu4g5hext/web.rar?dl=0), muchas graciasd de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mysql si no me equivoco tienes varias opciones en cuestion de librerias para realizar la conexion, yo use **sqlparse==0.1.19** y mi configuracion de conexion a la base de datos quedo asi:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
        'STORAGE_ENGINE': 'INNODB'
    }
}
```

Así que primero instala mediante pip sqlparse, y después en tu settings.py cambia la variable DATABASES que es la forma de conectarte a tu base de datos(tienes que tener previamente creada la base de datos mydatabase).

Saludos!

Comment: jajaja me respondiste mi otra pregnta, si eso de configuracion lo se, moviendo cosas simplemente cambie el nombre de i tabla por la otra que usaba y en mysql cabmbie el nombre de la tabla y una columna para no cambiarlo en todo el programa y ya anda todo bien solo que persiste lo de la otra pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Tienes q crear en tu phpmyadmin una bd con el mismo nombre de tu bd del settings.py y luego vas a tu proyecto a traves de tu consola y escribes python manage.py makemigrations
Lo siguiente
python manage.py migrate

Y todo estaria bien.